# Mapbox Basics: How do I use one style, multiple shapefiles, for multiple webpages

Tags: mapbox, shapefile

This should be easy, as it's surely a fundamental function of this service, but I'm stumped.

I have 60 shapefiles. The outcome that I want is that I have 60 different webpages, each showing a different map, but all using one consistent style.

I have the style built in Mapbox, and I can add the shapefiles to the "style" in mapbox - but that is arguing with my understanding of separating style from content. It seems like the shapefiles should live in some data repository, and the style should live somewhere else, and that the API would mash the two together as required. As far as I can tell, it doesn't work that way. I'm hoping some experienced user can simplify this for me, because I'm surely just missing some basic understanding of the general workflow for the service.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your shapefiles to [Mapbox studio](https://studio.mapbox.com/tilesets/), you create a source for your data on the Mapbox server.
You can then style your data further interactively on the run time using [filter property and expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/). Can you tell me why you want to make 60 different maps? It might be worth looking into some examples to like [create one map and filter it within the map view](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/).